# Upload ubuntu to RK2928 hdmi dongle chip

Tags: android, ubuntu, linux-kernel, operating-system

Recently brought Rockchip HDMI dongle http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/6034442013.html

I want to change the OS from Android to ubuntu.

## Steps followed:

1) Downloaded firmware from rockchipfirmware.com

2) Downloaded Img Mod tool to unpack and repack img

3) Downloaded IPushUpdate tool to push firmware to HDMI dongle.

## queries:

When I unpack the img file(default img of RK2928 chip hdmi dongle),contents are as follows,

- Image

  ```
   -- boot.img
   -- Kernel.img
   -- system.img
  ```
- data_512K.jffs2
- package-file
- parameter
- RK292xLoader(L)_V1.36.bin

What all things I need to modify in order to run my dongle in Ubuntu.

PS: I am newbie to this domain . This is my first kernel tweak.

Comment: This question is pretty old and I do not have an answer for you. What I do know is that those sticks run Android. The cpu in that stick is also a single core and more than likely Ubuntu will struggle if you do happen to to get it on

Comment: The biggest problem is not the limited CPU, but rather that the RK2928-generation sticks are typically streaming-only and so have little RAM and only a tiny amount of Flash.  They typically only run the lowest layers of Android underneath a native streaming program - no dalvik or ART VM, and no support for Android apps.  It's going to take a compact embedded Linux distribution rather than an expansive desktop one to fit on one of these, unless you can use something else for a filesystem.